# I am trying to run the setup from Parse.com into SWIFT. The "import Parse" seemed to work fine but then what is next?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I only know SWIFT from Apple. The Parse.com setup page is only documented for Objective-C. Any idea how to setup a SWIFT application?

Comment: Can you link to that page? If all that's needed is a translation from Obj-C to SWIFT, more people will be able to help if they can see the source instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup your IOS app for usage with a parse app, you can follow this. After that you can have look at parse docs which give you code snippets for swift as well.
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/connect-your-swift-application-to-parse-com/

If you run into errors after following the above, please do this:

- add "libsqlite3.dylib" also from "Link Binary With Libraries”
- Instead of

  Parse.setApplicationId(“your_application_key”, clientKey: “your_client_key”)

use

```
let ParseAppID:String! = "your_application_id"
let ParseClientKey:String! = "your_client_key"
Parse.setApplicationId(ParseAppID, clientKey: ParseClientKey)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhimanyu, I got it the stuff working. I am trying to use the PFObject instance method 'deleteEventually' in SWIFT but I get a compile error. Familiar with this issue.

Comment: Nope.. send over the actual error. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add all of this Library including parse
2. Don't forget to change NS.... to NSDictionary
3. create file .h  and add `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`  in it

Comment: Code snippets would be useful (are you being specific to swift here...)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to create the bridge file but it complains that it cannot find the file <Parse/Parse.g>